# easy_install virtualenv on python 2.4

Tags: python, virtualenv, easy-install

I'm trying to install the latest version of virtualenv using easy_install on a RHEL5.6 with python 2.4 and I'm receiving the following error.

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/virtualenv-1.6.3-py2.4.egg/virtualenv.py", line 500
    finally:
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've checked the virtualenv code https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/blob/develop/virtualenv.py#L500 and it seems like the syntax is correct for 2.4.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Changed in version 2.5: In previous versions of Python,
>   try...except...finally did not work. try...except had to be nested in
>   try...finally.

Looks like the latest virtualenv is not compatible with python <2.5

Comment: Ah yes. Indeed that's the case. I'll see if I can contact the developer of it and let them know.